# Error During using "INSERT INTO" SQL Query in Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, sql-insert

I have created an Azure SQL Server with SQL Database, as well as a table in that database named table1 with columns ID, FirstName, LastName, and DOB. However, when I try to use this statement:

```
INSERT INTO table1(ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB)
VALUES (1, "Rohit", "Karthik", "8/2/06")
```

it outputs an error:

```
Failed to execute query. Error: Invalid column name 'Rohit'.
Invalid column name 'Karthik'.
Invalid column name '8/2/06'.
```

(BTW: ID is of type int, and all the others are of type varchar)

Shouldn't the above SQL query in SQL Server insert the new row in that table?

I am not sure why this error is coming, please help.

Comment: Varchar or strings in ms sql are quoted with a single quote like this 'Rohit'

Comment: `VALUES (1, 'Rohit', 'Karthik', '8/2/06')`

Comment: I have tried single quotes as well, but still gives an error...

Comment: What error does it give with single quotes?

Comment: Never mind... It used to give an error, but after refreshing Azure query editor, it works.

Comment: However, my ID is actually a identity variable, and so whenever I add a new row and then delete and re add, it adds one to my I'd automatically. For example, my I'd was 1, deleted the row, and then I create the row -  the id turns 2. How do I make sure that it stays as 1 (as I deleted my first row)?

Comment: 1) Please don't change your question once people have started answering it, ask new questions if you have another question. 2) Thats how identity columns work - there is no (wasy) way around it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use single quotes for literal strings. In standard SQL, double quotes stand for column names - hence the error that you are getting:

```
INSERT INTO table1(ID, FirstName, LastName, DOB)
VALUES (1, 'Rohit', 'Karthik', '8/2/06')
```

Also, assuming that `DOB` is of a `date`-like datatype, you should consider using a more standard format (such as `YYYY-MM-DD`, or `YYYYMMDD`) instead of relying on your server's ability to infer the format (although SQL Server is really good at it).